# problem with dynamically add button with value & remove button option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. I made a text field.
2. getting value from text field and displaying on a button.
   -. Problem : i. when click a button so dynamically one button field should generate with remove option and that value should display on that input/button field.
   ii. the button should generate upto 5 time max.
   here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $button = $('#display_here').on('click', function() {
   $("#added_value_1") = $(this).text();

  });

  $('#myvaluefirst').on('input', function(e) {
    $button.text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Welcome</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" name="myvaluefirst" id="myvaluefirst">
<button type="button" id="display_here" name="display_here">value will display here</button><br>

<!-- This button should generate dynamically max 5 time whenever above button has been click.
and this button should display whenever text has been pass or not after the above button clicked. -->
<button type="button" id="added_value_1" name="added_value_1">Your value is</button>
<button type="button" id="remove_this_1" name="remove_this_1">Remove</button>
```

problem is: whenever 'value will display here' button clicked then one button should dynamically generate with remove option & value of that button max 5 time only.

Comment: What do you mean by ''one button should dynamically generate with remove.."?

Comment: @Bonfire there is a text field. whenever im inserting some value so it is displaying on a button. Now if i clicked that button so one more button field should display like dynamically generate with that value. which is mean whenever i'm click that button so dynamically should generate a button upto 5 time only with that value.

Comment: @Bonfire I have show reference button with remove option so that thing should dynamically generate whenever i click on the 'value will display here' button.

Comment: @Bonfire It is just like dynamically generating fields but also taking the value of above given text from button.

Comment: @Bonfire button field should dynamically generate max 5 time only. i can generate them but unable to add the value on them.

Comment: So, you want to display the 'Your value is' and 'Remove' buttons when 'value will display here' is clicked?

Comment: @Bonfire Please check the snippet. where you can see a text field with a button. after enter the value into the text field then value automatically displaying on the button field. now when i click that button so one field should generate dynamically with that value and i want that value should be delete also so for that i need one remove button too. that it.

Comment: @Bonfire Field should be dynamically added max 5 time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code gives you a dynamically filled button that on click generates a clone of itself along with a remove button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  addFillValueListener();
  addGenerateButtonListener();
});
function addFillValueListener() {
  const button = document.getElementById('generateButtons');
  document.getElementById('myValueFirst').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    button.value = this.value;
  });
}
function addGenerateButtonListener() {
  const button = $('#generateButtons').get(0);
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const remainingButtons = +button.getAttribute('data-remainingButtons');
    if(remainingButtons > 0) {
      button.setAttribute('data-remainingButtons', remainingButtons-1);
      cloneAndAppendDynamicButton(button, remainingButtons);
      generateAndAppendRemoveButton(remainingButtons);
    }
    remainingButtons == 0 && console.log('Maximum buttons reached');
  });
}
function cloneAndAppendDynamicButton(button, i) {
  const clonedNode = button.cloneNode(),
    div = $('#dynamicButtonsDiv').get(0);
  clonedNode.id = 'dynamicButton' + i;
  clonedNode.setAttribute('data-occurance', i);
  div.appendChild(clonedNode);
}
function generateAndAppendRemoveButton(i) {
  const rem = document.createElement('input'),
    div = $('#dynamicButtonsDiv').get(0);
  rem.type = 'button';
  rem.value = 'Remove';
  rem.setAttribute('data-occurance', i);
  rem.id = 'removeButton' + i;
  rem.addEventListener('click', removeOccurance);
  div.appendChild(rem);
}
function removeOccurance() {
  const occurance = this.getAttribute('data-occurance');
  $('#dynamicButtonsDiv > [data-occurance="'+ occurance +'"]').remove();
}
```

```css
#dynamicButtonsDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
}
#dynamicButtonsDiv > * {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myValueFirst" id="myValueFirst">
<input type="button" id="generateButtons" data-remainingButtons="5" value="Dynamic">
<div id="dynamicButtonsDiv"></div>
```